# Missing 'us' in "The knowledge enables to determine..."

Tags: grammar, verbs, verb-pattern

I have seen in at least two academic contexts sentences such as

> The knowledge enables to determine...

I would instead write

> The knowledge enables **us** to determine...

Since English is, in all of these cases, a non-native language for the writer, I am not sure if the word 'us' belongs in this type of sentences.

Is it correct to add the word 'us'? Is it correct to omit it?

Comment: In Russian we also omit **us** and this carries over into English (or Runglish rather) as "The new method allows to increase the total capacity of the plant by 20%".

Comment: **enable** and **allow** and **let** and **prevent** and **forbid** require a nominal complement and cannot take an infinitive complement alone.  Simple rewrite: "With this knowledge we can determine...".  The modal **can** is your friend.

Comment: There _is_ a variant without "us" : The knowledge enables determination of ... - this works because we turn the verb "to determine"  into the noun "determination".  (The same applies to allow,let,prevent and forbid).

Comment: Writing things like "... enables to determine..." is a common mistake among non-native speakers. It often comes up in academic writing, since a large amount of academic communication is in English.

Comment: If you want to avoid the use of "us" (which reduces the generality of the statement), you can also write "The knowledge enables xxx to be determined."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are absolutely right! You include 'us.'

It is called a *verb pattern.*

'Enable' is a verb that requires the pattern of `noun + to infinitive.`

> The knowledge enables *us to* determine...

A very good reference (including the verb in question) is on the [British Council website.](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-infinitive)